# Copying Bit Interval From A Variable To An Array

Tags: c

I have a setup of values stored in relatively bigger type of variables, which I have to store in again relatively smaller variables.

Here is the story of the problem: I have different sensor values in different types such as uint16_t, uint32_t and float. I want to store values separated in an uint8_t buffer array to transmit through an RF transmitter. For float type, I accept a finite significant value which then use integer multiplication to store it in an integer variable. Like this:

For this example, I want 3 digits after the comma,

```
float var1 = 12.3456789;
uint16_t var2;

var1 *= 1000;
var2 = (int) var1;
```

Which gives the output:

```
Var2: 12345 , Var1: 12345.679688
```

The summarization of the problem can be shown in the figure as,

[Problem summarization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OVkH.jpg)

Where black boxes are uint8_t type of elements in a 32 bytes of buffer, orange boxes are uint16_t variables which I want to separate into two uint8_t variables.

I tried to use memcpy() as,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    uint8_t buffer[32];
    uint16_t var1 = 64000;
    
    memcpy(&buffer[0], &var1, 1);
    memcpy(&buffer[1], &var1 + 1, 1);

    printf("var1: 0x%x\n\rbuffer[0]: 0x%x\n\rbuffer[1]: 0x%x", var1, buffer[0], buffer[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the output:

```
var1: 0xfa00
buffer[0]: 0x0
buffer[1]: 0x0
```

I thought about using bitwise operators to somehow separate, but failed. It would be great if you have any possible solution for this problem.

Comment: What about `memcpy(&buffer[0], &var1, 2);`?

Comment: A simple approach, never though like that. Right, arrays are just lined up in the memory, copying 2 bytes into first element solves right away. Thank you!

Comment: You can extract each byte from 32 bit, by using bitwise operators. source [bitwise](https://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/extract-bytes-from-int.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when you do this:

```c
memcpy(&buffer[0], &var1, 1);
memcpy(&buffer[1], &var1 + 1, 1);
```

You're effectively copying 1 byte of data each from `&var1`, and `&var1 + 1`.  So the big question here is "what is `&var1 + 1`?".

Since `var1` is a `uint16_t`, taking the address gives you a `uint16_t*`, incrementing that pointer by one will jump forward **two** bytes rather than just one.

If you cast the result of `&var1` to a `uint8_t`:

```c
memcpy(&buffer[0], (uint8_t*)&var1, 1);
memcpy(&buffer[1], (uint8_t*)&var1 + 1, 1);
```

You will get a result that might be closer to what you're expecting:

```
var1: 0xfa00
buffer[0]: 0x0
buffer[1]: 0xfa
```

If you wanted to bitshift data, you could do something like this:

```c
buffer[0] = var1 & 0xFF; // mask off top 8 bits
buffer[1] = var1 >> 8; // shift top 8 bits down to bottom 8 bits
```

Which yields the same result...

```
var1: 0xfa00
buffer[0]: 0x0
buffer[1]: 0xfa
```

Keep in mind that depending on your platform, you may run into [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issues if the source of the data represents it differently than the consumer of the data.